# How to split screen like ipad in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i want to make application in android Tablets like in ipad which have spliting screen,

How i can do that ? if any body have idea please send me!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read more: [Multi-pane Layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable using the [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). `Fragments` are available since Android 3.0, but there's also a Support Library that lets you use these API's from Android 1.6. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html): check http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/
it's a tutorial with sample application that uses the compatibility package (allows you to support from API 4), it may help

Answer (score 1):

this is not a 'feature' limited to iOS
you can easily do this in Android by using two vertical LinearLayouts and assigning them equal weight - to split the screen into half or Different weights to achieve something like the image you provided.

And of course, there are a lot of other ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the fragment xml file. then you have to write two xml files for CustomerList(Left Part) and CustomerInfo(Right Part). your activity should extends FragmentActivity. try with this:::

> 

```
<fragment class="ui.misc.Customers$CustomerList" 
android:id="@+id/customerlistfragmant" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="550px" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/> 
<fragment class="ui.misc.Customers$CustomerInfo" 
android:id="@+id/customerinfofragmant" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/regscreentwo" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="0px" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that if your split view is itself a fragment, you can't inflate its layout if it contains fragment tags (well, you *can*, but it's not guaranteed to work correctly). Instead, you have to programmatically add them with the `FragmentManager` returned by `Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the APIs described here: [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)